# Cytoscape position ignored if locked: false

Tags: layout, position, cytoscape.js

When I add a position property on a node, it is ignored unless I also specify locked: true.  I would like to specify initial positions on some nodes, yet still allow the user to move those nodes around.

Related (I think) - is there a way to let Cytoscape use a layout to determine node positions, then do a second pass and change them for any nodes that have a position property specified?  It would also work to have the layout ignore or not process any nodes that have positions specified.  That's what currently happens when I have locked set to true, but I'd like for it to happen if I have locked set to false on a node.

Perhaps another solution would be, how can I manually alter the positions after the layout is finished rendering?

Answer (score 0):

Don't run a layout on nodes you don't want moved.  Note that you have a layout specified in the init options.

Use [`preset`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#layouts/preset) at init, and make your own explicit [`cy.layout()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.layout) and/or [`eles.layout()`](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.layout) calls.  (The preset layout acts pretty much like a nop if all you specify is `{ name: 'preset' }`.)

Or keep your existing workflow and just unlock the nodes when the layout is done.